# Reconstruction using sinc

Tags: matlab, sampling, interpolation, reconstruction, sinc

[image: Expected Signal]

[image: Expected Signal]

The signal that I produce above. What is the reason for it to slide to the right? In oversampling at Nyquist rate can I make like below picture ? do you think the signal i produced at nyquist rate is correct, why so on the right? I was expecting to draw as below picture.
(Blue is the my signal, Red ones sampling and Yellow is the reconstruction using sinc.)
If needed I can share my all code. 
Thank you all.

Comment: Are you applying filter? It could be the filter delay.

Comment: No, I am not applying any filter. 
`x1reconstructed = zeros(1,length(t));
samples1 = length(t1);
for i = 1:1:length(t)
    for n = 1:1:samples1
        x1reconstructed(i) = x1reconstructed(i) + signal2(n)*sinc((t(i)-n*Ts1)/Ts1);
    end
end`
This is my reconstruct part for first oversampling at nyquist rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After seeing the code, I think the mistake may be

```
sinc((t(i)-n*Ts1)/Ts1)
```

Change it to

```
sinc((t(i)-(n-1)*Ts1)/Ts1)
```

An extra Ts1 delay was being applied to sinc. The index $n$ starts from 1 for MATLAB but it should start from 0.

Comment: I wanna ask one more question. Do you have any idea why sampling at nyquist rate some red stick is not exist true places ? The second is not in the middle, for example

Comment: "true places" means peaks?

Comment: yes i want to say peaks